# MDX: Create a set excluding entries from a different hierarcy

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

I am trying to create a custom set which excludes entries from another hierarchy, and I can't use the except function because of this. I have tried this, but I get an error message saying that the hierarchy is shown more than once in the query. Could someone please advise me on how to do this in the best way?

```
WITH 
SET [Market1] AS {
    [Market].[Market].[Market].&[103],
    -([Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[111], 
    [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[116], 
    [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[242], 
    [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[134])
}
```

EDIT: Here is my query (most of it is built from a query builder)

```
WITH 
SET [Market1] AS SUM((
    [Market].[Market].[Market].&[103],
    EXCEPT({[Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].ALLMEMBERS}, 
        {[Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[111], 
        [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[116], 
        [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[242], 
        [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[134]}
    )), [Measures].[Price])
SELECT NON EMPTY [Market1] ON ROWS
FROM ( SELECT ( { StrToMember("[Report Date].[Report Date].&[" + Str(Int(CDbl(Now()) - 38718)) + "]") } ) ON COLUMNS
FROM ( SELECT ( { [Travel Type].[Travel Type].&[101],
                  [Travel Type].[Travel Type].&[102],
                  [Travel Type].[Travel Type].&[103] } ) ON COLUMNS
FROM ( SELECT ( { [Departure Date].[Year].&[2017] } ) ON COLUMNS
FROM [Booking]))) 
WHERE ( [Departure Date].[Year].&[2017], 
        [Travel Type].[Travel Type].CurrentMember,
        StrToMember("[Report Date].[Report Date].&[" + Str(Int(CDbl(Now()) - 38718)) + "]") )
```

EDIT2: Managed to hack it together

```
WITH 
SET [Market1] AS (
    [Market].[Market].[Market].&[103],
    EXCEPT({[Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].ALLMEMBERS}, 
        {[Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[111], 
        [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[116], 
        [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[242], 
        [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[134]}
    ))
MEMBER Agg AS SUM  
   ( [Market1], [Measures].[Price]  
    )  
SELECT NON EMPTY Agg ON COLUMNS
FROM ( SELECT ( { StrToMember("[Report Date].[Report Date].&[" + Str(Int(CDbl(Now()) - 38718)) + "]") } ) ON COLUMNS
FROM ( SELECT ( { [Travel Type].[Travel Type].&[101],
                  [Travel Type].[Travel Type].&[102],
                  [Travel Type].[Travel Type].&[103] } ) ON COLUMNS
FROM ( SELECT ( { [Departure Date].[Year].&[2017] } ) ON COLUMNS
FROM [Booking]))) 
WHERE ( [Departure Date].[Year].&[2017], 
        [Travel Type].[Travel Type].CurrentMember,
        StrToMember("[Report Date].[Report Date].&[" + Str(Int(CDbl(Now()) - 38718)) + "]") )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it this way. You want to limit data from different dimensions, so you have to use tuple:

```
WITH 
SET [Market1] AS (
    [Market].[Market].[Market].&[103],
    EXCEPT([Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].ALLMEMBERS, 
        {([Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[111], 
        [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[116], 
        [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[242], 
        [Agency].[Nationality - Consortium - Agency].[Nationality].&[134]}
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! How can I sum all up? Now I get all the rows for all the agencies. I have tried the sum function, but I get an error message saying that the function expects a tuple for the argument, I have put my query in the original post

Comment: You cannot SUM in SET - you would have to create calculated member (like you did in Edit2) or do it directly in query. In the future it is better if you ask separate query when you have another. This way SUM will come up in title so more people can help you